# Workflow in sharepoint designer 2010 doesn't resume after pause

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I'm working on a workflow that needs to pause for a few minutes and then resume. My problem is that it never resumes after the pause. This is the workflow I'm testing it on.

```
Log start to the workflow history list
Pause for 0 days 0 hours 5 minutes
Log stop to the workflow history list
Stop the workflow and log completed
```

It never logs *stop*.
If I remove the pause the workflow works correctly.

I've read about a hotfix that has to do with timer in sharepoint http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21066 . But I wasn't able to install it so I think it doesn't apply to my version of SPD.

Any ideas?

ps. cross post from stackoverflow after I found out about this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't be a SharePoint Designer issue, but one with the SharePoint server itself.

Check Central Admin to see if the Workflow, Workflow Autocleanup, and Workflow Failover timer jobs are ok for your web application.

If you run a stsadm -o getproperty -pn job-workflow -url `http://sp2010` do you get `<Property Exist="No" />`?